# Updating rows by getting value from another Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the best procedure to update the rows by getting value from another database.

Below is the query that i am using for that.

```
UPDATE live_client_production.measurement_attachment t1
INNER JOIN live_client_uk.measurement_attachment t2
   ON t2.active = t1.active
  SET t1.content = t2.content 
where t1.id=97 
  AND t2.id=1;
```

For the next value to update the values for `t1.id` and `t2.id` are given

```
UPDATE live_client_production.measurement_attachment t1 
 INNER JOIN live_client_uk.measurement_attachment t2 ON t2.active = t1.active 
   SET t1.content = t2.content 
 where t1.id=98 
   AND t2.id=2;
```

Is there any way to set a limit or range so that `t1.id` and `t2.id` gets automatically incremented to a certain range.

Whats the best procedure to do this in mysql.

I humbly request you to please help me

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you can do a

```
where t1.id = (t2.id+96);
```

This makes me nervous though, because it is assuming it is always 96 between the two ids.  I'd be more comfortable if you could have the id's be the same, so that it was 98 in both tables, or if there were some code in both tables that identified them as being for the same data.  Then you have

```
where t1.id = t2.id
```

or

```
where t1.code = t2.code
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, bot ids should increment by 1 for each new update.

if you wanted, you could do just one update and make sure t1.id is always t2.id-96.

```
...
WHERE t1.id = t2.id-96
```

If you rely on iterating through several updates in one procedure, you can use variables, which you can restrict. Example:

```
set @id1 = 1;
set @id2 = 97;

while @id < 95 do

    UPDATE live_client_production.measurement_attachment t1
    INNER JOIN live_client_uk.measurement_attachment t2
    ON t2.active = t1.active
    SET t1.content = t2.content 
    where t1.id=97 
    AND t2.id=1;

    set @id1 = @id1+1;
    set @id2 = @id2+1;
end while;
```

Comment: getting error on executing this query Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'while @id < 95 do        UPDATE live_client_production.measurement_attachment t1' at line 1

Comment: you will have to run this within a procedure. it won't work as a standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the relative difference of the Id columns, and set a ceiling.

Something like

```
WHERE t1.id=t2.id+96
AND t1.id < @SomeCeilingValue
```